# SendMessage to child windows (Calculator try)

Tags: windows, winapi

so far i have written my code...

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr IParam);
    private const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
```

...

```
IntPtr win = FindWindow("CalcFrame", "Calculator");
        if (!win.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            IntPtr win2 = FindWindowEx(win, IntPtr.Zero, "CalcFrame", null);
            if (!win2.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ok");
            }
        }
```

And my question is, how can i send BM_CLICK to Calculator buttons..
And i dont get it, how can i choose windows and buttons with the same class

[image]

maybe someone will be so good and will explain me how to do this and maybe write some easy example.
Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: Why don't you use automation?

Comment: What's your question with the Spy++ screenshot? I don't follow what you mean. (If you do go with automation you might be able to walk the accessible object tree instead of enumerating child windows, but I still don't get your question so we might as well clear up the confusion anyway.)

Comment: I want to understand how can i simulate click to Calculator (for ex. press 2+2=) my only success was "FindWindow("XLMAIN", null);" "FindWindowEx(noteWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "EXCEL<", null);" "PostMessage(editWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VkKeyScan(msg[i]), 0);" set text to Excel formula bar. How can i click specific button with the same class.. i have found some examples but these doesnt work with Calculator.. thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use automation?

Comment: Thank you David Heffernan, i will check your suggestion, but maybe you can help me to click on Calculator 2+2= in this way :)

Comment: Yes. Use automation to do that. I get the feeling that you don't know that windows comes with a library for automation and that there's no need to grovel around faking input in this manner.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me go one step further and i understood that, no one can tell me how to do that in this way..

Comment: Well, automation is well documented and has many good tutorials. Very well supported from .net. You might need to do some independent research though.

Comment: http://blog.wibeck.org/2008/11/fun-with-uiautomation-and-calc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is two (or more) windows that have same class name and text, it's better to use [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function. Since you are using C#, [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows) is an example for this API function.

You can list all child windows and do whatever you want with them.